# caffe is conflicted with python cv2

Tags: opencv, caffe

I want to capture camera info with python ,and predict with caffe. When import caffe and import cv2 at the same time ,as the code:

```
import caffe
import cv2

# caffe.set_mode_cpu()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(1):
    # get a frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # show a frame
    cv2.imshow("capture", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**the following error will happen:**

objc[35793]: Class CaptureDelegate is implemented in both /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_videoio.3.4.dylib (0x104dc0938) and /Users/python-envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.so (0x1111d9380). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
src/tcmalloc.cc:332] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x7f9f37403fc0

I know the reason is that ,caffe and cv2 using different opencv lib , but how to solve this problem?What's more ,I don't want to rebuilt the caffe

Answer (score 1):

This is because caffe and opencv use different memory allocator. Caffe uses tcmalloc but opencv uses the default one. 
leveldb is dependent on gperftools, which contains tcmalloc.
Chick whether you've set USE_LEVELDB := 0 in the MakeFile.config of caffe. If you haven't, it's better to set USE_LEVELDB := 0 and rebuilt caffe. Or you can change the memory allocator used by opencv to be the same with caffe.